# Language parser in haskell

Tags: haskell, parsing

This is a recursive descent parser for simple language with following grammar:
PROGRAM <- {STATEMENT ';'}* RETURN_STMT ';'
STATEMENT <- NAME_BINDING | TYPE_DECLARATION
TYPE_DECLARATION <- named_param identifier
NAME_BINDING <- identifier '=' EXPRESSION
EXPRESSION <- (simple arithmetics with (), +-*/ and unary minus, arguments can be constants, named parameters or identifiers)
RETURN_STMT = 'return' EXPRESSION {',' EXPRESSION}* ';'

Module entry point is **parseGrammar**, resulting AST represented as **Program**

```
module LangParser(parseGrammar, Token(..), Result(..)) where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

data Token =
    Return              |
    Simple Char         |
    DecimalConst String |
    HexConst String     |
    NamedParam String   |
    Identifier String   |
    LexError String     |
    EOF
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Op = ONop | OPlus | OMinus | OStar | OSlash | ONeg deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord Op where
    compare ONeg _      = GT
    compare _ ONeg      = LT
    compare OStar _     = GT
    compare OSlash _    = GT
    compare OPlus b
        | b == OStar    = LT
        | b == OSlash   = LT
        | otherwise     = GT
    compare OMinus b
        | b == OStar    = LT
        | b == OSlash   = LT
        | otherwise     = GT
    compare _ _         = error "invalid comparison"

data Expr =
    EList Expr Expr |
    EAdd Expr Expr  |
    ESub Expr Expr  |
    EMul Expr Expr  |
    EDiv Expr Expr  |
    ENeg Expr       |
    EIntConst Int   |
    EVariable String    |
    ENamedParam String
    deriving Show

data Stmt = 
    SReturn [Expr]          |
    SDecl String String     |
    SBinding String Expr
    deriving Show
type Program = [Stmt]

data ParserState = ParserState { 
    prog :: Program, 
    exprStack :: [Expr], 
    opStack :: [Op],
    stmtIdent :: String,
    stmtParam :: String, 
    rest :: [Token] 
    } deriving Show

data Result a = Error Token | State a deriving Show

instance Monad Result where
    (Error e) >>= _     = Error e
    (State a) >>= f     = f a
    return              = State

instance Functor Result where
    fmap _ (Error t) = Error t
    fmap f (State a) = State (f a)

instance Applicative Result where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Alternative Result where
    empty = Error EOF
    Error _ <|> p = p
    State x <|> _ = State x

epsilon :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
epsilon = State

term :: Token -> ParserState -> Result ParserState
term t state@ParserState {rest = (x:xs)}
    | t == x    = State state{rest = xs}
    | otherwise = Error x 
term _ ParserState {rest = []} = Error EOF

termS :: Char -> ParserState -> Result ParserState
termS c = term (Simple c) 

termValue :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
termValue state@ParserState {rest = (DecimalConst x:xs)} = State state{exprStack = v : exprStack state, rest = xs}
    where v = EIntConst (read x)
termValue state@ParserState {rest = (HexConst x:xs)} = State state{exprStack = v : exprStack state, rest = xs}
    where v = EIntConst (read x)
termValue state@ParserState {rest = (NamedParam x:xs)} = State state{exprStack = ENamedParam x : exprStack state, rest = xs}
termValue state@ParserState {rest = (Identifier x:xs)} = State state{exprStack = EVariable x : exprStack state, rest = xs}
termValue ParserState {rest = (x:_)} = Error x
termValue ParserState {rest = []} = Error EOF

termIdent :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
termIdent state@ParserState {rest = (Identifier x:xs)} = State state{stmtIdent = x, rest = xs} 
termIdent ParserState {rest = (x:_)} = Error x
termIdent ParserState {rest = []} = Error EOF

foldExpr :: Op -> ParserState -> Result ParserState
foldExpr _ state@ParserState{opStack = []} = State state 
foldExpr stop state@ParserState{opStack = (op:_)} | op <= stop = State state
foldExpr stop state@ParserState{exprStack = (e:es), opStack = (ONeg:ops)} 
    = foldExpr stop state{ exprStack = ENeg e : es, opStack = ops } 
foldExpr stop state@ParserState{exprStack = (e1:e2:es), opStack = (op:ops)}
    = case op of
            OPlus -> foldExpr stop state{ exprStack = EAdd e2 e1 : es, opStack = ops }
            OMinus -> foldExpr stop state{ exprStack = ESub e2 e1 : es, opStack = ops }
            OStar -> foldExpr stop state{ exprStack = EMul e2 e1 : es, opStack = ops }
            OSlash -> foldExpr stop state{ exprStack = EDiv e2 e1 : es, opStack = ops }
            _ -> error "invalid op in stack"
foldExpr _ _ = error "invalid state in fold"

exprS :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
exprS = expr >=> foldExpr ONop

expr :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
expr s = expr' s <|> (termNeg >=> expr') s
    where 
    termNeg = termS '-' >=> (\state -> State state{opStack = ONeg : opStack state})
    expr' st = (termValue >=> exprRest) st <|> 
        (termS '(' >=> exprS >=> termS ')' >=> exprRest) st


exprRest :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
exprRest s = 
    (termOp '+' >=> expr) s <|> 
    (termOp '-' >=> expr) s <|> 
    (termOp '*' >=> expr) s <|> 
    (termOp '/' >=> expr) s <|> 
    epsilon s
    where
    termOp c = termS c >=> foldExpr (op c) >=> (\state -> State state{opStack = op c : opStack state}) 
    op '+' = OPlus
    op '-' = OMinus
    op '*' = OStar
    op '/' = OSlash
    op _ = error "bad op"

retexprs :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
retexprs = exprS >=> exprList
    where 
    exprList s = (termS ',' >=> retexprs >=> action) s <|> epsilon s
    action state@ParserState {exprStack = (e1:e2:es)} = State state{exprStack = EList e2 e1 : es}
    action _ = error "2"

retStmt :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
retStmt = term Return >=> retexprs >=> termS ';' >=> action
    where
    action state@ParserState {exprStack = (e:es)} = State state{prog = SReturn (reverse $ unroll e []) : prog state, exprStack = es}
    action _ = error "3"
    unroll :: Expr -> [Expr] -> [Expr]
    unroll (EList e1 e2) es = unroll e2 (e1:es)
    unroll e es = e:es

nameBinding :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
nameBinding = termIdent >=> termS '=' >=> exprS >=> action
    where 
    action state@ParserState {stmtIdent = ident, exprStack = (e:[])} 
        = State state{prog = SBinding ident e : prog state, exprStack = []}
    action _ = error "invalid binding"

paramDecl :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
paramDecl = termNamedParam >=> termIdent >=> action
    where
    action state@ParserState{stmtParam = param, stmtIdent = ident} 
        = State state{prog = SDecl param ident: prog state}
    termNamedParam state@ParserState {rest = (NamedParam x:xs)} = State state{stmtParam = x, rest = xs} 
    termNamedParam ParserState {rest = (x:_)} = Error x
    termNamedParam ParserState {rest = []} = Error EOF

statements :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
statements s = (statement >=> termS ';' >=> statements) s <|> epsilon s
    where statement st = paramDecl st <|> nameBinding st

parseProgram :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
parseProgram s = (statements >=> retStmt) s <|> retStmt s

parseGrammar :: [Token] -> Result ParserState
parseGrammar st = parseProgram (ParserState [] [] [] "" "" st)
```

I'm looking for code improvements. For example, repeated this lines looks ugly:

```
NNN ParserState {rest = (x:_)} = Error x
NNN ParserState {rest = []} = Error EOF
```

Also, I would like to separate parser states for parsing statements and expressions. Writing two separate types will require doubling number of epsilon/term/termIdent functions, which I hope to avoid.

Comment: Are your operators all supposed to have equal precedence? I think your code could be made to look much better if a little more order could be placed on `foldExpr`, `exprS`, `expr` and `exprRest`

Comment: No, there is normal arithmetic precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A suggested change,

```
data MyType = TValue | TIdent | TNamedParam

termX :: MyType -> ParserState -> Result ParserState
termX t state = case (t, rest state) of
  (TIdent, Identifier x:xs) -> vstate' x xs
  (TNamedParam, NamedParam x:xs) -> vstate' x xs
  (TValue, HexConst x:xs) -> vstate xs (v' x)
  (TValue, DecimalConst x:xs) -> vstate xs (v' x)
  (TValue, NamedParam x:xs) -> vstate xs (ENamedParam x)
  (TValue, Identifier x:xs) -> vstate xs (EVariable x)
  (_ , (x:_)) -> Error x
  (_ , []) -> Error EOF
  where v' = EIntConst . read
        vstate xs v = State state{exprStack = v: exprStack state, rest = xs}
        vstate' x xs = State state{stmtParam = x, rest = xs}

termValue = termX TValue
termIdent = termX TIdent
termNamedParam = termX TNamedParam
```

I think this is better than repeating the state@ again and again.

I think the below might also be nice since it is avoiding the repetition of foldexpression

```
foldExpr _ state@ParserState{opStack = []} = State state 
foldExpr stop state@ParserState{exprStack = ex, opStack = (x:ops)} = case process ex x of 
  Just ev -> foldExpr stop state{ exprStack = ev, opStack = ops } 
  Nothing -> State state
  where process (e:es) ONeg = Just $ ENeg e : es
        process (e1:e2:es) OPlus = Just $ EAdd e2 e1 : es
        process (e1:e2:es) OMinus = Just $ ESub e2 e1 : es
        process (e1:e2:es) OStar = Just $ EMul e2 e1 : es
        process (e1:e2:es) OSlash = Just $ EDiv e2 e1 : es
        process e y | y <= stop = Nothing
```

---

A slightly terse version of exprRest. I think the do notation is clearer here.

```
exprRest :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
exprRest s = foldr (\op acc ->
  (termOp op >=> expr) s <|> acc) (epsilon s) ['+', '-', '*', '/']
  where
     termOp c = termS c >=> foldExpr (op c) >=> \state ->
                    State state{opStack = op c : opStack state}
    op '+' = OPlus
    op '-' = OMinus
    op '*' = OStar
    op '/' = OSlash
    op _ = error "bad op"
```

---

Here is the only change I made, Look at this pattern,

```
((termOp '+' >=> expr) s) <|>
   ((termOp '-' >=> expr) s) <|>
      ((termOp '*' >=> expr) s) <|>
         ((termOp '/' >=> expr) s) <|>
epsilon s
```

Which is same as

```
let myfn op = (termOp op >=> expr) s in
((myfn '+') <|> (myfn '-') <|> (myfn '*') <|> (myfn '/') <|>
epsilon s
```

This can be replaced with a fold

```
fold (\opfn acc -> opfn <|> acc) (epsilon s) [myfn +, myfn  -, myfn  *, myfn /]
```

equivalently, ...

---

So I used your question as an excuse to understand lenses. Here is the resulting code. See if you like it. (I don't claim it is good as I am still learning lenses)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, FlexibleContexts #-}
module LangParser(parseGrammar, Token(..), Result(..)) where
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad

import Data.Lens.Template (makeLenses)
import Data.Lens.Lazy

data Token =
    Return              |
    Simple Char         |
    DecimalConst String |
    HexConst String     |
    NamedParam String   |
    Identifier String   |
    LexError String     |
    EOF
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Op = ONop | OPlus | OMinus | OStar | OSlash | ONeg deriving (Show, Eq)
instance Ord Op where
    compare ONeg _      = GT
    compare _ ONeg      = LT
    compare OStar _     = GT
    compare OSlash _    = GT
    compare OPlus b
        | b == OStar    = LT
        | b == OSlash   = LT
        | otherwise     = GT
    compare OMinus b
        | b == OStar    = LT
        | b == OSlash   = LT
        | otherwise     = GT
    compare _ _         = error "invalid comparison"

data Expr = EList Expr Expr |
            EAdd Expr Expr  |
            ESub Expr Expr  |
            EMul Expr Expr  |
            EDiv Expr Expr  |
            ENeg Expr       |
            EIntConst Int   |
            EVariable String    |
            ENamedParam String
  deriving Show

data Stmt = SReturn [Expr]          |
            SDecl String String     |
            SBinding String Expr
  deriving Show
type Program = [Stmt]

data ParserState = ParserState { 
    _prog :: Program, 
    _exprStack :: [Expr], 
    _opStack :: [Op],
    _stmtIdent :: String,
    _stmtParam :: String, 
    _rest :: [Token] 
    } deriving Show

$( makeLenses [''ParserState])

data Result a = Error Token | State a
  deriving Show

instance Monad Result where
    (Error e) >>= _     = Error e
    (State a) >>= f     = f a
    return              = State

instance Functor Result where
    fmap _ (Error t) = Error t
    fmap f (State a) = State (f a)

instance Applicative Result where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap

instance Alternative Result where
    empty = Error EOF
    Error _ <|> p = p
    State x <|> _ = State x

epsilon :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
epsilon = State

term :: Token -> ParserState -> Result ParserState
term t state = case state ^. rest of
  (x:xs) -> if t == x then State (rest ^= xs $ state) else Error x 
  [] -> Error EOF

termS :: Char -> ParserState -> Result ParserState
termS c = term (Simple c) 

data MyType = TValue | TIdent | TNamedParam

termX :: MyType -> ParserState -> Result ParserState
termX t state = case (t, rest ^$ state) of
  (TIdent, Identifier x:xs) -> vstate' x xs
  (TNamedParam, NamedParam x:xs) -> vstate' x xs
  (TValue, HexConst x:xs) -> vstate xs (v' x)
  (TValue, DecimalConst x:xs) -> vstate xs (v' x)
  (TValue, NamedParam x:xs) -> vstate xs (ENamedParam x)
  (TValue, Identifier x:xs) -> vstate xs (EVariable x)
  (_ , (x:_)) -> Error x
  (_ , []) -> Error EOF
  where v' = EIntConst . read 
        vstate xs v = State ( exprStack ^= v: (exprStack ^$ state) $ rest ^= xs $ state )
        vstate' x xs = State ( stmtParam ^= x $ rest ^= xs $ state)

foldExpr :: Op -> ParserState -> Result ParserState
foldExpr stop state = case opStack ^$ state of
  [] -> State state
  (x:ops) -> case process ex x of 
    Just ev -> foldExpr stop (exprStack ^= ev $ opStack ^= ops $ state)
    Nothing -> State state
  where process (e:es) ONeg = Just $ ENeg e : es
        process (e1:e2:es) OPlus = Just $ EAdd e2 e1 : es
        process (e1:e2:es) OMinus = Just $ ESub e2 e1 : es
        process (e1:e2:es) OStar = Just $ EMul e2 e1 : es
        process (e1:e2:es) OSlash = Just $ EDiv e2 e1 : es
        process e y | y <= stop = Nothing
        ex = exprStack ^$ state

exprS :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
exprS = expr >=> foldExpr ONop

expr :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
expr s = expr' s <|> (termNeg >=> expr') s
    where 
    termNeg s = termS '-' s >>= State . (opStack ^%= (ONeg :))
    expr' st = (termX TValue >=> exprRest) st <|> (termS '(' >=> exprS >=> termS ')' >=> exprRest) st

unroll :: Expr -> [Expr] -> [Expr]
unroll (EList e1 e2) es = unroll e2 (e1:es)
unroll e es = e:es

exprRest :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
exprRest s = 
    (termOp '+' >=> expr) s <|> 
    (termOp '-' >=> expr) s <|> 
    (termOp '*' >=> expr) s <|> 
    (termOp '/' >=> expr) s <|> 
    epsilon s
    where
    termOp c = termS c >=> foldExpr (op c) >=> State . (opStack ^%= (op c :))
    op '+' = OPlus
    op '-' = OMinus
    op '*' = OStar
    op '/' = OSlash
    op _ = error "bad op"

retexprs :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
retexprs s = do a <- exprS s
                b <- termS ',' a
                c <- retexprs b
                action c <|> epsilon s
    where 
    action state = case getES state of
      (e1:e2:es) -> State (myprog state e1 e2 es)
      _ -> error "2"
    myprog state e1 e2 es = setES state (EList e2 e1 : es)

retStmt :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
retStmt s = do a <- term Return s
               b <- retexprs a
               c <- termS ';' b
               action c
    where
    action :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
    action state = case getES state of
      (e:es) -> State (myprog state e es)
      _ -> error "3"
    myprog state e es = prog ^= SReturn (reverse $ unroll e []) : (state ^. prog) $ setES state es

nameBinding :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
nameBinding s = do a <- termX TIdent s
                   b <- termS '=' a
                   c <- exprS b
                   action c
    where 
    action :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
    action state = case getES state of
      (e:[]) -> State (myprog state e)
      _ -> error "invalid binding"
    myprog state e = prog ^= SBinding (state ^. stmtIdent) e : (state ^. prog) $ setES state []


paramDecl :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
paramDecl s = do a <- termX TNamedParam s
                 b <- termX TIdent a
                 action b
    where
      action :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
      action state = State (prog ^= SDecl (state ^. stmtParam) (state ^. stmtIdent) : (state ^. prog) $ state)

setES state es = (exprStack ^= es) state
getES state = state ^. exprStack 

statements :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
statements s = do b <- statement s
                  c <- termS ';' b
                  statements c <|> epsilon s
    where statement st = paramDecl st <|> nameBinding st

parseProgram :: ParserState -> Result ParserState
parseProgram s = do b <- statements s
                    retStmt b <|> retStmt s

parseGrammar :: [Token] -> Result ParserState
parseGrammar st = parseProgram (ParserState [] [] [] "" "" st)
```

Comment: It's exactly how it supposed to be. In comparison left operand is always on operations stack and right operand is just taken from token stream. Left-associative operations with equal precedence should compare as GT, right-associative as LT. This is required for arithmetically correct :) parsing.

Comment: And I can't derive from Ord because OPlus and OMinus have equal precedence, but are different.

Comment: So is it correct for Op to have an Ord instance? Isn't one of the requirements for an Ord class, a total ordering? I suppose, it may not lead to problems here, but I was taught to be very careful to only define instances of Typeclasses if you can provide the same guarantees of their interfaces.

Comment: I see your point. Will remove Ord and change to plain comparison function.

Comment: Could you explain change in exprRest? I don't get how it works.

Comment: @blaze updated. See if you can follow.

Comment: Thanks, got it now. Looks like this makes parser less explicit in self-describing grammar, but I need to think again about it.